# Changed column in two last rows for each entry

Tags: sql

I want to monitor change of Important column (Important) and display only those rows where there was a change. For each document, each change is recorded with serial change ID (e.g. Document #1 has change #1 in nonimportant column, change #2 in non-important column, and change #3 in IMPORTANT column) - and I want to see in the output that DocNum #1, changeID #3, 'Column Changed'.

I am trying to catch the changes in the Important column for the last change instance of each document (DocNum) - and display only rows where the change was in the Important column.

I thought about something like this, but this doesn't work :(

```
    SELECT 
        DocNum, 
        changeID, 
        'Important' AS 'Column Changed' 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT changeID, 
            DocNum, 
            Important
        FROM ADOC
        ) AS DifferenceInImportant
    WHERE 
        changeID IN (
            SELECT 
                TOP(1) TT0.changeID
            FROM 
                ADOC TT0 
            WHERE 
                TT0.DocNum=DocNum 
            ORDER BY TT0.changeID DESC
        )
    GROUP BY changeID, DocNum
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

example: input data like (without the empty rows, just for good orientation)

```
DocNum changeID DueDate
000001 00000001 0101-18
000001 00000002 0201-18
000001 00000003 0201-18
000001 00000004 0301-18

000002 00000001 0201-18
000002 00000002 0201-18

000003 00000001 0101-18
000003 00000002 0201-18

000004 00000001 0301-18
000004 00000002 0401-18
000004 00000003 0401-18
```

expected result (only those rows, where the last change - the entry with the last change ID - was in the DueDate)

```
DocNum changeID DueDate
000001 00000004 'Changed Column'
000003 00000002 'Changed Column'
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please show sample data and expected result? Is this SQL Server you are using or which other DBMS?

Comment: Hello @ThorstenKettner, of course I can. I added it.

Comment: Your query is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: I still don't understand. For docnum 000001 the last change happened on 0301-18 and you show it. For docnum 000003 the last change happened on 0201-18 and you show it. For docnum 000002 the last change happened on 0201-18. But here not only one change occurred, but two. Same for docnum 000004 on 0401-18. Is this the reason you are not showing docnum 000002  and 000004? Or is there another reason?

Comment: Yeah @ThorstenKettner, because there wasn't any change in the DueDate column in the last change (some other change in any different - not displayed - column) which is not important for us.

Comment: Er, so it's not about two changes on the last date versus only one change, but about some column you are not showing? You should add this, so we see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using the ANSI-standard `lag()` function.  Assuming `important` does not contain `NULL` values:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             lag(important) over (partition by docnum order by changeid) as prev_important
      from ADOC a 
     ) a
where prev_important is null or prev_important <> important;
```

This can be modified to handle `NULL` values, but this gets the idea across.

Comment: Please note that for `LAG()` window function you need SQL Server 2012+. You might use a `ROW_NUMBER()` and join by the resulting rank +N on 2008+.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: window functions are not limited to SQL Server (actually SQL Server was quite late to _that_ party) Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Firebird, Teradata and many other database products support window functions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh I thought it was tagged as SQL-Server, my bad.